# How much flash memory is there in the microcontroller?

Tags: stm32

I have an STM32F303CBT6 microcontroller.
On the [ST site](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f302cb.html), the volume of the flush is 128 kB.

[image]

In [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00094349-stm32f302xb-c-d-e-and-stm32f302x6-8-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) flash up 256 kB.

[image]

In this case, register "Flash memory size data register" contains the value `128` [kB].

There is also 128 kb in the stlink utility.

[image]

But in the cleaning window, the page costs 128 pages of 2 kB. This amounts to 256 KB.

[image]

I didn't get it. What is the size of the flash?

Comment: The "B" in STM32F303CBT6 stands for "128KB" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#Part_number_decoding). The 256KB version would be STM32F303CCT6. I can't tell you what the cleaning window indicates.

Comment: you have as much memory as your DS says. ST-Link utility is not the source of information. There is a bug in the program

Comment: @Codo, Add an answer, pls. I will mark it.

Comment: Often the bigger parts will be sold as smaller parts if areas of their flash don't test correctly, so your part may physically have more than 128 k, but I wouldn't trust the extra flash for anything more critical than a hobby project which could fail at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "B" in STM32F303CBT6 stands for "128KB" (see [STM32 Part Number Decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#Part_number_decoding)).

The 256KB version would be STM32F303C**C**T6.

I can't tell you what the cleaning window indicates.